# Inconsistencies in the Contribution Detail report

Tags: civireport, reports

I'm trying to chase down an inconsistency someone reported in the Contribution Detail report. It doesn't happen with all contacts (in fact I've only seen it in the one they reported, so far).

There are two donations in this person's history that don't show up correctly:

- A $15 donation shows up as $30
- A $25 donation shows up as $125

The summary at the bottom of report for a date range correctly counts 10 rows, but then indicates 15 contributions instead of 10.

[image: Contrib detail report]

If I pull the same contributions in a Bookkeeping Report, they come out correctly.

I can't find anything different about the contributions in question. Has anyone seen anything like this or have any idea where to go next in troubleshooting? I don't think it matters but this is a Drupal 7 site.

Comment: In case you are using Extended Report there have been some patches for it so may be worth checking you are on the latest version eg what link are you referring to? eg civicrm/report/contribution/detailextended?reset=1

Comment: I wasn't, but I am now -- and it solves this issue while providing more options on the report to boot. Thanks!

Comment: cool - posted as an Answer - can you pls Accept so SE thinks this is 'done'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Extended Reports extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport) ;-)